# How to send when an event has ended in discord.py

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, discord.py, python-datetime

I am trying to get an output like this, in which it tells when the message was sent

[image]

I successfully got when a message was sent

```py
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"**{title}**", description=f"<:854745395314163784:910908229897297940> Ends in {lenght}")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url='https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/D14-NqrYBiv91a8nM8tVD4b0SuN-CAUlmooEq0dtWsM/https/kaj.gg/r/kq902alos9a.png?width=80&height=80')
    emb.set_footer(text = f"{winners} Winner")
    msg_2 = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await msg_2.add_reaction(emoji)
    id = msg_2.id
    created = msg_2.created_at
    print(created)
```

[image: Here is the output]

but I cant figure out how to return a message like "Ended a Few seconds ago" or "Ended few hours ago"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you sent uses Discord's built-in timestamp format, outlined [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting). You can obtain a Unix timestamp by using datetime's `timestamp()` function on `msg_2.created_at`, something like this for your example:
`f"<t:{int(msg_2.created_at.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp())}:R>"`
You can then include that string in a message normally.

Comment: it is showing ended 6 Hours ago, is this related to time zones?

Comment: It is, thanks for pointing it out and apologies for not including it in the original answer. I've updated it now.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!